# QGIS killed 'Items Properties' panel?

Tags: qgis, export

- QGIS 2.6.1
- Microsoft Windows 7
- Relative Newbie to QGIS; old hand at drawing software

Think I have corrupted this on my actual file that I'm working on.

Yes, I know that I can right click and get the panel back, but it's blank!

Have tried deleting export templates, tried opening on new machine!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select an item on the composer page, for the properties to be shown for that item. Looks like you only have a map. Try to select it, with the select/move item tool in the print composer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found it.

See that small box that says #Map0, clicked on it and Items Properties re-appeared![image]

Comment: Either that or use the items on the page...

Answer (score 0):

In the Layout, you will see "view" on the top panel
Click "view" and it will produce a drop down list,
scroll down to "panel"
Click it and a multiple option drop down list will appear.
Now select "item properties"